# Laravel Forge Can't Connect to MySQL through Socket

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-forge

I've just started using Laravel Forge, but I can't seem to login to MySQL after SSHing into the server.  Each time I try:

```
mysql -uforge -p
Enter password: thepassword
```

I get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

I've got my environment variables set using Forge, so it shouldn't be using the defaults:

```
DB_HOST=thehostip
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD=theotherpassword
```

and I've left the database configuration as:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),


'connections' => [

    'mysql' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],

    ...
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the solution turned out to be that using 512MB server is just inadequate.  After emailing Laravel Forge and explaining my issue it was suggested that updating to at least a 1GB server would solve the problem, and it did.  Once I provisioned a 1GB server I could get into MySQL via SSH with no issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with forge but by giving this a quick look, it looks like your MySQL host is an IP address as you explained, and that was my first thought when you said forge, from what I know of the service it is cloud based and the DATABASE is located on a different machine/IP address what you want to do is the following command:

```
mysql --host [thehostip or hostname] -u forge -p
Enter password: thepassword
```

What you are doing right now is accessing the mysql on the same machine. I'm sorry if I am wrong but the fact that you described the configurations as `DB_HOST=thehostip` leads me to believe it is a network address.
**UPDATE**
Just looked at the error it returns and I'm pretty sure I'm right, 
Also another thing you are doing wrong is the -u requires a space before the username only the -p parameter for the password requires no spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Give this command a shot:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this and it responded with: "start: Job failed to start"

Comment: What does the log say? cat /var/log/mysql/error.log

Comment: If I do that I get: "cat: /var/log/mysql/error.log: Permission denied"

Comment: you will have to run that as 'sudo' too, then.

Comment: Thanks for the help that did work when I used 'sudo' and I got a list of errors, but it turned out to be a memory issue that was solved by provisioning a new 1GB server, and not using a 512MB server I originally spun up to see how Forge worked.